# STM32F4 clock 60Mhz

Tags: clock, stm32f4, pll

I want to set my STM32F446 controller his clockfrequency to 60MHz. 
I thought I could do it, but without results.

I am using an STM32F446 -nucleo board. I used STM32CubeMX to generate my code. After that didn't work, I searched on the web and found the same code (exept for the values).

If I program my controller with this code. The values of the clockfrequency isn't right, or my controller does nothing.

Can you guys help me?

```
RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

__PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 60;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1
                            |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLRCLK;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5);

HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

/* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What didn't work? How did you check?

Comment: @Tibo I tested it with very many toggles of a GPIO in a while loop. I know the while-loop creates some delay. But is still need to get an output frequency of 30MHz. If I change the values of the PPLs a bit, it doesn't work.

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct1.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct1.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct1.Pull      = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct1.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct)

    while()
    {
     GPIOA -> ODR = 0x0002
    GPIOA -> ODR = 0x0000
        ....
}

Comment: A pure-software loop doesn't sound like a good idea to achieve 30MHz. You should first check that your GPIO are actually clocked at the highest possible rate (peripheral clock != core clock), check that you set the GPIO speed as high as possible (as they call it in CubeMX), and consider using a hardware timer instead of a loop.

Comment: Also this link may be relevant: This link might be relevant: https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3a%2f%2fmy.st.com%2fpublic%2fSTe2ecommunities%2fmcu%2fLists%2fcortex_mx_stm32%2fMaximum%20Output%20Speed&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=3319

Comment: @Tibo You are right, de output frequency isn't the clockfrequency.
But when I use him in default clock frequentie(180MHz) I get a output frequency of 90Mhz my way, with toggling the GPIO.
 The problem to work with the timer is that in the application wherefor I'm working, I need to communicate(parallel) at a frequency of 30Mhz. So i can't lose some clockpulses.

Comment: You're still trying to bit-bang a USB PHY over ULPI?! You really need to just hook your PHY up to the STM's ULPI pins and use the internal module to communicate with it. Anything else is just a waste of time.

Comment: @brhans: thanks for pointing this out. I now understand that OP has a XY[Z...] problem. I'll just stop trying to be helpful on this thread.

Comment: @brhans I see where the problem is.

Comment: to verify what clock you are really getting use one of the timers.  I think the cortex-m has a systick you can use, and compare that to a wall clock (stop watch, second hand, etc aim for enough ticks to get 30 seconds or something for reasonable accuracy)

Comment: I prefer to toggle an led state every 10 to 30 seconds and compare that to a second hand on a watch to get an idea of how I have set the pll.   might want to use the internal clock to start with just to get a feel for whether or not you are actually measuring the clock right.

Comment: @brhans Yes I still want to do my ULPI over my GPIO, the reason is because I need to adjust the varisense technology of the USB-PHY chip (USB3343).  When I use the ULPI pins of my STM32 controller I can't use this technology.

Answer (score 1):

you should try the RCC example in the firmware package for your stm32f4 mcu. And implement error checking:

```
if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
  /* Initialization Error */
  Error_Handler();
}


\\and:

if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
{
  /* Initialization Error */
  Error_Handler();
}

if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
  /* Initialization Error */
  Error_Handler();
}
```

after implementing this you can run in debug mode and insert break points at Error_Handler();

Comment: He goes into the error handler two times, at the first if and the thirth.

Answer (score 0):

You do use internal HSI oscilator, check MXCube and select external HSE oscilator if this is a problem you are asking for.

Comment: No i want to use the HSI oscilator.